# Why do I get blank grey background instead of animations in PyGame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am creating the `Environment` class. The function `init` should build the simulated environment, while the function `run` should execute different events in this environment during 10 seconds.

Below I share some major parts of my code. When I run `env = Environment("TEST") env.run()` (see below), the window with grey screen appears. Then it closes in 10 seconds. Nothing is visible in this screen. It's just a grey background. However, I do not get any error message.

What am I doing wrong in the `Environment` class?

Just to mention that the same code worked fine when I had the whole code of `Environment` placed directly in `main` loop, i.e. when `Environment` class has not existed.

```
import numpy as np
import pygame
import random

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (20, 255, 140)
GREY = (210, 210, 210)

SCREENWIDTH = 1000
SCREENHEIGHT = 578

IMG_WORKER_RUNNING = "images/workers/worker_1.png"
IMG_WORKER_IDLE = "images/workers/worker_2.png"
IMG_WORKER_ACCIDENT = "images/workers/accident.png"


class Worker(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    RUNNING = 0
    IDLE = 1
    ACCIDENT = 2
    NUMBER_OF_ACCIDENTS = 0
    IMAGE_CACHE = {}

    def __init__(self, idw, image_running, image_idle, image_accident,
                 all_sprites, location, *groups):
        # Each state has it's own image
        self.images = {
            Worker.RUNNING: pygame.transform.scale(
                self.get_image(image_running),
                (45, 45)
            ),
            Worker.IDLE: pygame.transform.scale(
                self.get_image(image_idle),
                (20, 45)
            ),
            Worker.ACCIDENT: pygame.transform.scale(
                self.get_image(image_accident),
                (40, 40)
            )
        }

        self._layer = 2
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        self.idw = idw
        self.reset(location)

    def reset(self, location):
        self.state = Worker.IDLE
        self.ticks_in_state = 0

        self.location = location
        self.image = self.images[self.state]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)

        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.speed = random.randint(1, 3)

    def get_image(self, key):
        if not key in Worker.IMAGE_CACHE:
            Worker.IMAGE_CACHE[key] = pygame.image.load(key)
        return Worker.IMAGE_CACHE[key]


class Environment:
    def __init__(self, title):
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption(title)

        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.workers = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.fences = pygame.sprite.Group()

        # create a worker
        idw = 1
        Worker(idw, IMG_WORKER_RUNNING, IMG_WORKER_IDLE,
               IMG_WORKER_ACCIDENT, self.all_sprites, (50, 50), 
               self.workers)

    def run(self):
        carry_on = True
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        simulation_time = 10  # time in seconds

        while carry_on:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if (event.type == pygame.QUIT) or (simulation_time == 0):
                    carry_on = False
                    pygame.display.quit()
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

                simulation_time -= 1

            agent_action = 0
            send_alert = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 1)

            if send_alert > 0.2:
                agent_action = 1

            self.all_sprites.update(self.screen, agent_action)
            self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    env = Environment("TEST")
    env.run()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the line `def reset(self, location):`. After fixing that I'm getting `AttributeError: 'Worker' object has no attribute 'get_image'`. Is the code you are running the same as the code posted?

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer: Fixed. Here I posted a simplified version of my code. Sorry, I missed `get_image` method and `IMAGE_CACHE` variable. Now it should be the same as I have in my laptop and you should see a blank grey screen.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/  -- still there are missings. `IMAGE_CACHE` is not in worker class, to reproduce pictures have been set and also `GeoFence` is not available. This code isn't very helpful. Also it seems that you haven't done any debugging yourself.

Comment: @colidyre: I've just debugged it in my laptop. Now it's running and reproduces the issue that I commented in the thread.

Comment: Just wondering. Are you really supposed not to keep a copy of the Worker object you create in `__init__(...)`? Seems like it should be added to a workers list as a member of the env object. Maybe the worker object gets destroyed when you exit `__init__`. Just a hunch, not sure.

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen: Could you please post an answer with your suggestion and demonstrate how it works?

Comment: @ScalaBoy I don't feel a hunch is worthy of a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the `all_sprites` argument in the `Worker.__init__` method to the `__init__` method of the `Sprite` class, so that the sprite will be added to this group.

```
pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, all_sprites, groups)
```

You could also rearrange the parameters of the `__init__` method and pass the two groups as the last arguments (they will be added to the `groups` list).

```
# In the Worker class.
def __init__(self, idw, image_running, image_idle, image_accident,
             location, *groups):

# Pass the two groups as the `groups` argument.
Worker(idw, IMG_WORKER_RUNNING, IMG_WORKER_IDLE,
       IMG_WORKER_ACCIDENT, (50, 50), self.all_sprites, 
       self.workers)
```

In the while loop you need to blit a background surface or fill the screen every frame in order to clear it, then draw the sprites and finally update the screen with `pygame.display.flip()` (you need to indent it in your example).

```
while carry_on:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT) or (simulation_time == 0):
            carry_on = False
        # You probably don't want to decrement the
        # simulation_time once per event. Dedent
        # this line to decrement it once per frame.
        simulation_time -= 1

    agent_action = 0
    send_alert = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 1)

    if send_alert > 0.2:
        agent_action = 1

    self.all_sprites.update(self.screen, agent_action)
    # Blit a background surface or fill the screen.
    self.screen.fill((0, 40, 0))  # Fill with dark green.
    # Blit all sprites.
    self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
    # Update the screen.
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)
```

Comment: If you need a timer, check out these solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720665/countdown-timer-in-pygame

Comment: Thanks. I followed your indications. I have problems with `all_sprites`. If I pass `all_sprites` in the `groups` list as you showed, then in my real code I get the error `NameError: name 'all_sprites' is not defined` at the lines: `self.icon = Icon(self.emo_images[self.emo_state], self.rect.bottomright). self.icon.add(all_sprites)` in the init` function of `Worker`. However, I was not getting this error when I was not using `Environment` class. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: If you need the `all_sprites` argument in the `__init__` method, then either pass it as a separate argument again or replace `all_sprites` with `groups[0]`. The `groups` argument is actually a list and the star `*` means all arguments that you pass after `location` will be appended to this list. So if you pass `self.all_sprites, self.workers` as the sixth and seventh arguments, groups will be a list with `self.all_sprites` as the first and `self.workers` as the second element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs